# Jquery Mapster stroke on mouse over

Tags: jquery, colors, render, mouseover, stroke

I am using this settings to render different areas of map with different color.

http://jsfiddle.net/6maJw/

Problem is, that I also need stroke on mouseover, but when I will use `stroke: true`, stroke is drawn after render in every colored area. But I need it to be seen only on mouseover.

It can be seen here

http://prntscr.com/11l66x

Stroke must be visible only on mouseover